# Parse string like Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3=val3 in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I want to parse a string return from a toString method of a class in c# with pattern like:

Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3:val3 and so on

where the val1, val2 or val3 can be datetime or alphamuneric value.

Please suggest any standard approach to do it.

Comment: So the seperator can be both `:` and `=`?

Comment: you can split the string by , which would give you key value pair kind result. further seperation by : would give you what you need

Comment: why you think that you need this? possibly better will be use reflection for getting field values?

Comment: Are you sure that the last separator is the `=` char? Because apart from that it looks like a part of a JSON message, and these can be deserialized using `JavaScriptSerializer` or similar classes as @Sachin mentioned.

Comment: You can also use a regex to extract all pairs at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using *Split*, e.g.

```
String data = "Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3=val3";

// items is the array of {"Field1", "val1", "Field2", "val2"...}
String[] items = data.Split(',', ':', '=');  // <- Put all separators here
```

Then parse the values if need:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) { // <- Field Name
      String field = items[i];
      ...
    }
    else { // <- Value
      DateTime value = DateTime.Parse(items[i]); // <- Some kind of parsing; see also ParseExact, TryParse
      ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what i will do:

```
String data = "Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3=val3";
//split data into array of string with format like "key:value" or "key=value"
String[] keyValues = data.Split(',');
//for each string get the value and the key
foreach (var keyValue in keyValues)
{
    var pair = keyValue.Split(':', '=');
    var key = pair[0];
    var value = pair[1];
    var parsedValue = ParseValue(value);
}

private object ParseValue(string value)
{
    //Parsing string to various type of object is another problem to face
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can split the string manually and parse the values, it's far faster to use a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) to extract all pairs at once. In this particular case, it's also less complicated.

The pattern `(?<key>\w*)[:=](?<value>\w*),?` will split extract the key/value pairs from the input string directly to groups named `key` and `value` eg:

```
var searchInput = "Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3=val3";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<key>\w*)[:=](?<value>\w*),?");
var matches = regex.Matches(searchInput);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var key = match.Groups["key"].Value;
    var val= match.Groups["value"].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}",key,val);
}
```

To parse the values, you can use [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to convert the value to a datetime. If this fails, you can treat it as a string, eg:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
object parsedValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(val, out parsedDate) )
    parsedValue=parsedDate;
else 
    parsedValue=val;
```

In this case you have to modify the original regex to include the date separators in the `value` pattern:

```
(?<key>\w*)[:=](?<value>[\w-:]*),?
```

If the `=` separator was added in error, you can remove it from the pattern:

```
(?<key>\w*)[:](?<value>[\w-:]*),?
```

This can all be cleaned up a bit using LINQ and anonymous types to get just the key/value pairs:

```
public static object DateOrString(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        return input;
    DateTime parsedDate;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(input, out parsedDate))
        return parsedDate;
    return input;
}

...

var searchInput = "Field1:val1,Field2:val2,Field3:val3,Field4:2013-12-11T01:00:00";
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<key>\w*)[:=](?<value>[\w-:]*),?");
var matches = regex.Matches(searchInput);

var pairs = from Match match in matches
    select new {
        Key = match.Groups["key"].Value, 
        Value = DateOrString(match.Groups["value"].Value)
    };
```

The pairs can now be converted to a Dictionary, a List, or whatever other structure is suitable.

Printing the pairs from the last example produces this:

```
Key: Field1 Value: val1
Key: Field2 Value: val2
Key: Field3 Value: val3
Key: Field4 Value: 11/12/2013 1:00:00 am
```

A [.NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) of the code [is here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/uhutqw)

Comment: The regex is giiving a key/ value with only key=Field1 and value = val1 instead of groups with all the fields and values.

Comment: For what input? For the example, I get 4 pairs, the last of which has a date value. Added a [.net fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/uhutqw) of the example